# Sun type 5 keyboard via serial port replicator

Tags: keyboard, serial-port

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP G60 laptop with a [Targus serial port replicator to USB](http://www.emtcompany.com/targus-pa070-usb-mobile-port-replicator/101331778.html) and a [custom cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ALULFX0) between the keyboard and the replicator

I ran `modprobe sunkbd`.

Nothing works for the Type 5.
The type 5c beeps when I plug it in or boot up but none of the keys work.
What am I missing?

I've pluged the Type 5c in via the mini DIN plug under the keyboard that is for the mouse because you can't detach the 5c cable from the keyboard.

Comment: 'none of the keys work' -- how are you testing that?

Comment: sorry, i should have retracted this. 
I am using a PC and the keyboard is sun. 
They communicate over serial differently. 
You can buy or make a converter thing but it's not worth all that.

Thanks for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

You can build this adapter easily yourself if you have some soldering skills. See [https://www.xapek.org/dw/notiz:sun_type_5](https://www.xapek.org/dw/notiz%3asun_type_5)